# Change column value on identical indexes

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates, rename

Have the following dataframe:

[image]

Sometimes the index is duplicate and then I want to change the value in the column 'Hotspot'. So prograding_feature_polygon_30 should be changed to prograding_feature_polygon_30_1 and the second on index 0 to prograding_feature_polygon_30_2.

The same on index 1, so again the values should be changed to prograding_feature_polygon_30_1 and prograding_feature_polygon_30_2. And so on...

Indexes are not always duplicate and if not, the value in Hotspot should remain the same. Anyone knows an easy way to do this?

Regards,

Dante

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data sample**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.repeat([*'ABCD'],[2,1,3,1]),
                   'b': [*range(7)]}, 
                  index=np.repeat([*range(4)],[2,1,3,1]))

print(df)

   a  b
0  A  0
0  A  1
1  B  2
2  C  3
2  C  4
2  C  5
3  D  6
```

**Problem**

For each duplicate in the index, we want to add a consecutive number to the values in column `a`. So, `A_1, A_2` for index value `0`, and `C_1, C_2, C_3` for index value `2`. Values without duplicates (`1` and `3`) should be unaffected.

**Solution**

```
df.a = np.where(df.index.duplicated(keep=False),
         df.a + '_' + df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str),
         df.a)

print(df)

     a  b
0  A_1  0
0  A_2  1
1    B  2
2  C_1  3
2  C_2  4
2  C_3  5
3    D  6
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`df.index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) with param `keep=False` to get an array with `True` for duplicates, `False` for non-duplicates.
- Use this array inside [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). If `True`, we want `df.a + consecutive number`, else simply `df.a`.
- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the index, and apply [`.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to enumerate items per group. `add(1)` to start at `1`, instead of `0`. Finally, use `astype(str)`, in view of the concatenation with `df.a`.